# How does if mountpoint -q $1 work

Tags: shell-script, mount

I understand that mountpoint is used to determine if a given directory is a mountpoint or not. However, what I don't understand is its combination of it and the if statement.

I tested a code snippet from the Internet:

```
#!/bin/bash

if mountpoint -q $1; then
  echo "$1 is mounted"
else
  echo "$1 isn't mounted"
fi
```

It works! But I am not sure how it works (especially -q means to be quiet). I tried to put the condition into a pair of double square brackets:

```
if [[ mountpoint -q $1 ]]; then ...
```

And it doesn't work. 
So I want to ask what the internal mechanism is that makes this if statement work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mountpoint` command will exit with a status [zero if the directory or file is a mountpoint, non-zero if not](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mountpoint.1.html#EXIT_STATUS).

That's what the `if` command is checking for. Whether the command exits successfully (zero status) or not (non-zero status.) (It has nothing to do with whether there's any output or not.)

---

To explain the last part... The `[[ ... ]]` construct will check whether there's a string or not, but in that case you would need to capture the output using something like `[[ $(mountpoint $1) ]]`, but something like that would only work if the command would only print output in that case, so something like this would be more realistic `[[ $(mountpoint $1 | grep 'is a mountpoint') ]]`. But that's inferior... Just use `-q` and check the exit status directly, that's how this is meant to be used!

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!I have one more question: In fact I suspected that mountpoint -q $1 could output something and thus I tired echo $(mountpoint -q $1) and nothing is output (as expected from  the -q option). Now I understand it is exit code rather than its output that matters. Would it be possible to display the exit status in one sentence like "echo -some -options $(mountpoint -q $1)"? (I understand that echo $? would work but that would be at least two sentences)

Comment: @Mamsds Yes, it's possible. For that you need `&&` and `||` operators. These are just slightly different from an `if..else..fi` statement, since they work with left-associativity, which means in this command `moutpoint -q "$1" && echo "it's a mountpoint"` will only echo something if the left-most command succeeds. By that same rule, `moutpoint -q "$1" && echo "it's a mountpoint"` ||  echo "Not a mountpoint or echo command failed"` will only echo last thing if the left-most group failed  ( imagine having parenthesis around first two commands)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Hi Sergiy, what I want to show the exit code. For example, if the exit code of (mountpoint -q $1) is 1, I want echo to show me 1 as if it is a normal output.

Comment: @Mamsds This should work: `$(mountpoint -q $1; echo $?)`. Though I can't see why you'd want to do that... Anyways, I hope it helps.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Many thanks! Yes it is not practically necessary just I would like to learn how to make echo work on this occasion...